# Find common number divisible by six different numbers

Tags: divisibility, divisible-groups

If there is recipe to find this - I would like to find the first common number divisible by the following six numbers- 260,
380, 460,560,760 and 960.

How does one calculate the numbers I need?

Any direction would be useful.

Comment: You're looking for the first three multiples of the l.c.m. of the given numbers.

Comment: This too [link](https://www.calculatorsoup.com/calculators/math/lcm.php) gives three number for LCM. I need the first number which can be divided by all the 6 numbers I have. How do I proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The prime factorizations of the numbers are:

$260 = 2^2×5×13$

$380 = 2^2×5×19$

$460 = 2^2×5×23$

$560 = 2^4×5×7$

$760 = 2^3×5×19$

$960 = 2^6×3×5$

If the number needs to be divisible by all, it needs to be divisible by $2^6, 3, 5, 7, 13, 19, 23$ (Why?).

If you multiply these, you get ______.

Comment: 38176320. Works for me. Thanks

Comment: @jam_27 No prime factorization is needed if you remove obvious common factors, e.g. see my answer. For large numbers prime factorization is very slow, but removing common factors is fast, since we have a fast algorithm (euclidean gcd algorithm).

Comment: I accepted the prime factorization approach as I find the LCM approach confusing (but that just me)

Answer (score 0):

$\DeclareMathOperator{\lcm}{lcm}$
As I said, you have to calculate the l.c.m. of the six numbers. The l.c.m.  is associative, so you may group some numbers when it's easier to compute. Furthermore, all these numbers are divisible by $20$, so
$$\lcm(260,380,460,560,760,960)=20\lcm(13,19,23,28,38,48)$$
On the other hand, $\lcm(19,38)=38$, $\;\lcm(28,48)=4\lcm(7,12)=4\cdot 7\cdot12)=336$, so
$$\lcm(260,\dots,960)=20\lcm(13,23,38,336)$$
Continuing, we have $\:\lcm(38, 336)=2\lcm(19,168)=2\cdot19\cdot168=6384$, $\;\lcm(13,23)=13\cdot23=299$, and finally
$$\lcm(260,\dots,960)=20\lcm(299,6384)=20\cdot299\cdot 6384=20\cdot1\,908\,520=\color{red}{38\,176\,320}$$
if my computations are correct.

Comment: Incorrect because you used used $360$ vs. OP's $460\ \ $

Comment: @BillDubuque: Thanks for pointing it! I'll fix that in a moment.

Answer (score 0):

$\begin{align} {\rm Hint\!:}\ \  &\ \, 20[19,13,23,\,28,\,38,\,48],\ \ \, \ \ \ {\rm with}\,\ \ [a,b,c] := {\rm lcm}(a,b,c)\\[.2em]
&=\, 20[13,23,2[14,19,24]]\ \ \ \ \ \ \ {\rm by}\ \ 19\mid 38\\[.2em]
&=\, 20[13,23,2[\ \ 7,19, 24]]\ \ \ \ \ \ \ {\rm by}\ \ 2^1\,||\,14,\, 2^2\mid 24;\\[.2em]
&=\, 20(13\!\cdot\! 23(2(7\cdot 19\cdot 24)))\ \ \ \ {\text{by lcm = product for pair coprimes}}\\[.2em]
&=\, 38176320\end{align}$